# Does PHP 7.1 consider 0 to be Undefined?

Tags: php

I and looping through some MySQL records. I am checking to see if `$customer['id'] == 0`. I have a customer place holder for "No Customer" set at id 0. During my loop, when it does the check it works fine, except for when it reaches customer 0. It gives `Notice:  Undefined index: id`. I can output the ID and it shows 0 just fine.

Here is the code I am running:

```
<?php
$RecordsetData = getQuotes();
$totalRows_RecordsetData=count($RecordsetData);
if($totalRows_RecordsetData >= 1){
    foreach($RecordsetData as $row_RecordsetData){
        
        $customer=getCustomers($row_RecordsetData['customer']);
        echo "Customer ID: ".$row_RecordsetData['customer']."<br>";
        echo "Customer Name: ".$customer['firstname']." ".$customer['lastname']."<hr><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

The function `getQuotes()` returns all quote data which also contains a column called `customer` which is the ID of the customer in the `customers` table.

The function `getCustomers($id)` returns data about the customer that you pass the ID for.

This is the output I get:

[image: output]

So it does look like it isn't getting the user. However here is the code for `getCustomers`

```
function getCustomers($id=null,$uuid=null){
    global $db;
    if($id){
        (int)$id;
        $rows = $db->row('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = ?', $id);
    }elseif($uuid){
        $uuid=clean($uuid);
        $rows = $db->row('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE uuid = ?', $uuid);
    }else{
        $rows = $db->run('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id != ? ORDER BY lastname ASC', 0);
    }
    if(count($rows) <= 0){
        return array(); // returning false, but so that count() doesn't present a '1' value.
    }else{
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

I am passing the customer ID of `0` so it should be using `$db->row('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = ?', $id)`. The rest work fine.

If I just do a `SELECT * FROM` customers `WHERE id = 0` in MySQL it returns just fine.

Comment: If you can do `echo $customer['id']` with no error, then it shouldn't given error for the `if` statement, either. Show your code.

Comment: No, PHP doesn't consider 0 to be undefined. That error means that the `$customer` array doesn't have an `id` key at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0` is not `undefined`, but it *is* `false` in a boolean context.

So this check in your getCustomers function

```
if($id){
```

is not doing what you think it is. It is in fact falling through to the else block when `0` is passed.

If zero is a valid id here then you probably really wanted to check `!is_null($id)` instead.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much for your help!